# Magento 1.8 Fatal Error Call to Member Function toHTML() In Admin Panel

Tags: function, magento, lamp, member

I am trying to edit one of the attributes in the Magento admin panel. When I click on any of them from Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in /var/www/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Main/Abstract.php on line 217

I have seen the fix on Stackoverflow and other sites saying to edit page.xml from

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```

however, that does not solve this issue. The code here should all be original. How can I fix this error on the admin control panel?

Comment: You are wrong way this is not proper solution, have you use any extension for catalog ?

Comment: I have several extensions installed. How would I know which could be causing this problem?

Comment: which is similar to attribute or catalog that is causing the problem

Comment: The only one I can think of is a bulk image extension. I can't remove it. The site would be unmanageable without it. How can I troubleshoot further?

Comment: first of all find out which extension causing the problem then debug that extension code and resolve the error this is only one way. Thanks